# I want to fetch max date (latest interaction) for each client id and from there I want to get last 90 days' interactions

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

my table consists of different client interactions' sessions. Different transactions of a particular client has a master id attached to it.

1. I need the latest interaction time of a master id and then get 90 days worth of data back from there.
2. Also, some consumers will have < 90 days of data - how should I extract them separately?

So far, I have written the following code to achieve the solution to first one. Get the max date for each master id, get 3months back date and finally fetch all the data where interaction_time>= interaction_time_3m

But I am not sure if it is the correct way to proceed.

```
Select *
FROM
(SELECT *, 
 DATEADD(MM, -3, MAX(interaction_time) OVER (PARTITION  BY master_id)) as interaction_time_3m
 FROM clean_dd s
 WHERE interaction_time>='2023-01-01') t
 where interaction_time>= interaction_time_3m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu can follow this simple solution -

1. get max(interaction time) mx and for each client.
2. get all data when this date is <= interaction time  for each client. Now if difference between interaction time  for each client is <90 then filter them out separately.

```
with mx as (select MAX(interaction_time) mxdt,master_id FROM clean_dd s group by master_id)
select s.master_id, interaction_time
from clean_dd s
join mx on mx.master_id =  s.master_id and DATEADD(MM, -3, mx.mxdt )<=interaction_time
```

And you can get second output if you change last dateadd condition to -

```
and datediff(day, mx.mxdt, interaction_time) < 90
```

Comment: hey @Koushik Roy thanks for the help. Yes, this function looks simple and understandable. However, it gives error near mxdt and mx.

Comment: There were some syntax error. I fixed it. pls try the new SQL now.